# Publish jar along with bootJar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a spring boot gradle project with 3 modules:

1. canonicalizer (bootJar)
2. loader (bootJar)
3. utils (jar, not executable)

I'm trying to publish it using different approaches, but the logic is the next:

```
subprojects {
    // ... other configurations ...

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = "${projGroupId}"
                artifactId = project.name
                version = "${projVersion}"

                from components.java

                if (project.tasks.getNames().contains('bootJar')) {
                    artifacts {
                        bootJar
                    }
                } else if (project.tasks.getNames().contains('jar')) {
                    artifacts {
                        jar
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        repositories {
            maven {
                url = nexusReleaseRepoURL
                credentials {
                    username  nexusUsername
                    password  nexusPassword
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
> Task :canonicalizer:generateMetadataFileForMavenJavaPublication FAILED
> Task :autoLintGradle
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':canonicalizer:generateMetadataFileForMavenJavaPublication'.
> Cannot publish module metadata where component artifacts are modified.
```